# "Unknown attribute: avatar" when uploading image with Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I ran this migration:

```
rails generate paperclip user avatar
```

It created this migration file:

```
class AddAttachmentAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

I added this to my edit user registration view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :avatar %> <br>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
```

When I try to upload an avatar in edit user registration, I receive this error:

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in Devise::RegistrationsController#update
unknown attribute: avatar

**EDITS**

I added

```
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
    end
```

to my user model and now I don't get the error, but now the profile picture just prints out as a link. I think I can find an answer to that.

Comment: Worth noting you also require the has_attached_file in the model as stated in an answer below or you get the same unknown attribute error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
end
```

to my UsersController to fix the issue.

Answer (score 13):

Are you sure you're permitting the `:avatar` attribute through your controller's permits?
Also, have you mentioned the following line of code in your model?

```
has_attached_file :avatar
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I do have "has_attached_file :avatar" in my model. Sorry about that.